# Different Numpy reshaping to 3D array syntax's

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm looking at LSTM neural networks. I saw code like this below:

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
```

This code is meant to change a 2d array into a 3d array but the syntax looks off to me or at least I don't understand it. For example I would assume this code below as a 3d syntax

```
np.reshape(rows , columns, dimensions)
```

Could someone elaborate what the syntax is and what it is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Function `numpy.reshape` gives a new shape to an array without changing its data. It is a numpy package function. First of all, it needs to know what to reshape, which is the first argument of this function (in your case, you want to reshape `X_train`).

Then it needs to know what is the shape of your new matrix. This argument needs to be a tuple. For 2D reshape you can pass `(W,H)`, for three dimensional you can pass `(W,H,D)`, for four dimensional you can pass `(W,H,D,T)` and so on.

However, you can also call `reshape` a Numpy matrix by `X_train.reshape((W,H,D))`. In this case, since `reshape` function is a method of `X_train` object, then you do not have to pass it and only pass the new shape.

It is also worth mentioning that the total number of element in a matrix with the new shape, should match your original matrix. For example, your 2D `X_train` has `X_train.shape[0] x X_train.shape[1]` elements. This value should be equal to `W x H x D`.

Comment: Thanks makes sense now. I want to ask quickly. TO get the number of rows you perform np.shape[0] and the columns np.shape[1]. For dimensions is it np.shape[2]?